# jQuery $.post returning "Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

Getting a stack size exceeded error doing an ajax post in jquery

```
$('#challengeForm').submit(function(e) {
    var ajaxUrl = admin.ajax_url;
    var emailInput = $(this).find('input[name="email"]');
    var formId = $(this).find('input[name="formId"]');
    $.post(ajaxUrl,{action:'challengeFormSubmit',email:emailInput,listId:formId},function(data) {

        console.log(data);

    },'json');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I ran some `console.log` debug and found the error is called at the `$.post`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the values (not the objects):

```
$('#challengeForm').submit(function(e) {
    var ajaxUrl = admin.ajax_url;
    var emailInput = $(this).find('input[name="email"]').val();
    var formId = $(this).find('input[name="formId"]').val();
    $.post(ajaxUrl,
        {
            action:'challengeFormSubmit',
            email:emailInput,
            listId:formId
        },
        function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        'json'
    );
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Don't really see a difference in your code vs mine other than  you restructured it a bit.

Comment: You are missing the `.val()` part. Check it out.

Comment: derp! Been a long day

Answer (score 0):

Your function is being resubmitted. Try the following:

1. Move `e.preventDefault();` to the top of the function.
2. End the function with `return false;`

Comment: If the `e.preventDefault()` wouldn't work - the submit will be moving him to the other page, so the preventDefault is actually working. This is not his problem.

Comment: hence returning false. It's just good hygiene to prevent the default behavior of an event before starting a lengthy process.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you call `preventDefault()` at the top or bottom.